# Passing variable doesn't work unless I define the variable in function

Tags: javascript, css, function

The `e` parameter as it is in the function below does now work, but if it is defined within the function it works.

Here its a parameter and called at the bottom: ( fails )

```js
function getRotVal( e ) {
  var el = document.getElementById( e ),        //  e is a parameter in the function
      st = window.getComputedStyle( el, null ),
      tr = st.getPropertyValue( 'transform' ) || "FAIL",
      values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
      a = values[0],
      b = values[1],
      c = values[2],
      d = values[3],
      scale = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b),
      sin = b/scale,
      angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));

      return angle;
}

var box = document.getElementById( 'box' );
var result = getRotVal( box );

alert( result );
```

```css
.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 0.75rem auto;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate( 15deg );
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
</div>
```

And here I define the variable in the function: ( it works )

```js
function getRotVal() {
  var el = document.getElementById( 'box' ),        //  e is defined inside function
      st = window.getComputedStyle( el, null ),
      tr = st.getPropertyValue( 'transform' ) || "FAIL",
      values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
      a = values[0],
      b = values[1],
      c = values[2],
      d = values[3],
      scale = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b),
      sin = b/scale,
      angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));

      return angle;
}

var result = getRotVal();

alert( result );
```

```css
.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 0.75rem auto;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate( 15deg );
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
</div>
```

I would like this function to be dynamic and accept different variables so the second snippet isn't that great. How can I get the first snippet to work and keep e as a variable?

Comment: One `var` per variable.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I thought I saw a typo but I was mistaken. What do you mean? I'm seperating variables with commas.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I found the typo in the second snippet. I used `;` instead of a comma. Still the first snippet is broken?

Comment: using comma to separate thing that depends on each other is not beautiful. Split them out to separate statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you are passing the DOM element to `getRotVal` function and again you are using `getElementById` on the DOM element.

So just comment the first line of el and pass the function parameter `e` directly to getComputedStyle like below

```
// var el = document.getElementById( e ),        //  e is a parameter in the function
  st = window.getComputedStyle(e, null),
```

**Code snippet:**

```js
function getRotVal(e) {
  // var el = document.getElementById( e ),        //  e is a parameter in the function
  var st = window.getComputedStyle(e, null),
    tr = st.getPropertyValue('transform') || "FAIL",
    values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(','),
    a = values[0],
    b = values[1],
    c = values[2],
    d = values[3],
    scale = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b),
    sin = b / scale,
    angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));

  return angle;
}

var box = document.getElementById('box');
var result = getRotVal(box);

alert(result);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 0.75rem auto;
  background-color: #222;
  transform: rotate( 15deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Good, now you're declaring global variables.

Comment: You need to put `var` before `st =`

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, Barmar. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your function calls `document.getElementById(e)`, so it expects the argument to be an ID, not an element. You should call the function like this:

```
var result = getRotval('box');
```

Either that, or don't call `getElementById()` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass object reference in function parameter because 
you allready convert it to reference witnin a function in the below line.

```
var el = document.getElementById( e );
```

so edit where you are calling getRotVal function to like as:

```
var result = getRotVal("box");
```